# How can I handle NotFoundHttpException in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, api

I'm developing API in Laravel 8. I want to handle NotFoundHttpException to json response. But App\Exception\Handler updated in Laravel 8. By default render method does not exist. So I do not understand what I want to do. I have read in Laravel docs.

Comment: You can override rendor method as it is exist in `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler`

Comment: Can you give full example?

Comment: check this hander has render method. https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.html

Comment: are you not sending the `accept` header that specifies the request wants json back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a custom callback as per the documentation, `App\Exceptions\Handler`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

public function register()
{
    $this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
        return response()->json(...);
    });
}
```

If you send the correct `accept` header with your request the exception handler will return a JSON response already though.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Error Handling - Rendering Exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#rendering-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on Xamp , edit vhosts where lvauth is your project and directory name

DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\lvauth\public"
  ServerAdmin lvauth
  
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

Answer (score 0):

if you are running on Xamp , edit vhosts where lvauth is your project and directory name
VirtualHost lv.auth:80
DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public"
ServerAdmin lv.auth
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel">[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZmPJ.png)
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
Directory
VirtualHost